# Firefox Cookie Max Expiration Date set to 7 days without specification

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, cookies, setcookie

With this code I tried to create a cookie that remains existant for a year. It works fine on Chrome, i could see by checking "Storage" in the dev tools. But on Firefox, the Max limit for Expiration appears to be set to 7 days without me specifying that anywhere (Every time I create a cookie set to more than seven days, it defaults back to seven). I couldn't find any other people who experienced the same problem as me.

I tried:

```
function set_cookie(name, value, expires = 365) {
    let cookie = name + "=" + value + "; SameSite=None; Secure; path=/; "
    if (expires !== false) {
        const date = new Date()
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (expires * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
        let expiry = "expires=" + date.toUTCString()
        cookie += expiry
    }
    document.cookie = cookie
}
```

and:

```
document.cookie = "consent=true; max-age=300000000; SameSite=None; Secure"
```

neither of those code snippets got the cookie to be expired in more than seven days on Firefox. All worked fine on Chrome though :/

Comment: 300000000 seconds is way more than the 400 days the specs require

Comment: This likely has to do with tracking prevention. Safari has implemented similar storage time limits already, even for localStorage. https://www.cookiestatus.com

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and fixed it by pausing my Ad Blockers. I think it might have something to do with the Total Cookie Protection ?

Hope this helps !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).